# Emscripten does not link from static library

Tags: c++, emscripten

I have a program I would like to cross compile via Emscripten. So I created a static library `foo_core` and now try to link it into a html page via:

```
$ em++ -std=c++11 -s VERBOSE=1 main.cpp.o -o example.html libfoo_core.js
VERBOSE is on, this generates a lot of output and can slow down compilation
adding ___cxa_atexit and deps atexit
adding _atexit and deps 
warning: unresolved symbol: _Z12fooiiii
```

Now I of course then try to find out why `_Z12fooiiii` is missing. In the end doing:

```
$ grep -r _Z12fooiiii *
example.html: __Z12fooiiii(50, 50, 50, 255);
libfoo_core.js:,0,__Z12fooiiii,0,__ZNSt3__16locale5facetD2Ev,0,__ZTv0_n12_NSt3__113basic_istreamIwNS_11char_traitsIwEEED1Ev,0,__ZNSt3__112system_errorD0Ev
libfoo_core.js:function __Z12fooiiii($r, $g, $b, $a) {
```

reveals that, the function is actually present in `libfoo_core.js`.
So I am pretty confused now and would really appreciate someone explaining to me why this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you compile bitcode AND the library has the suffic `.bc` (e.g. `libfoo_core.bc`)!

Comment: how does one specify the creation of a ".bc" "arvhive" in the "static library" compile link emcc command?  Is it the same as gcc ? I havn't found any samples.

Comment: in my case I use cmake. There is an option EMSCRIPTEN_GENERATE_BITCODE_STATIC_LIBRARIES